# Avoid copying string literals to class string data member that does not change

Tags: c++

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  // Other constructors...

  Foo(const char* s) : bar{s} {}
  Foo(std::string_view s) : bar{s} {}
  Foo(std::string&& s) : bar{std::move(s)} {}
private:
  std::string bar;  // only changes upon Foo being moved from
  // other functions and data members...
};
```

The defined constructor would copy a string literal to `bar` with `Foo("a string literal")`. Is there a way to avoid copying when a string literal is given?

What I would like to achieve is that `Foo` accepts a string in its constructor. Afterwards, it only needs to read that string. Meanwhile, the string must outlive `Foo`. Is there a way to do so without incurring copying of the string within `Foo`?

One idea is to use a variant:

```
class Foo {
public:
  // Other constructors...

  Foo(const char* s) : bar{s} {}
  Foo(std::string_view s) : bar{std::string{s}} {}
  Foo(std::string&& s) : bar{std::move(s)} {}

private:
  std::variant<std::string, const char*> bar;
  // Other functions and data members...
```

However, the first constructor still can't distinguish a short-lived char array from a long-lived char array such as a string literal. I understand it is possible to use a tag in the constructor to distinguish the two situations. While I'm open to this idea, the concern is that it is too error prune as the compiler issues no warning when using the wrong tag.

Is there a way to avoid copying this string?

Comment: *"can't distinguish a short-lived char array from a long-lived char array such as a string literal..."* I don't think this can be done as overload resolution can't distinguish based on lifetime of the argument.

Comment: Also it seems like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Normally, there is no need to these kind of things.

Comment: This may be possible if some variation of [P1045](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1045r1.html) is included in the standard.

Comment: using std::string bar means you want bar to own it's char buffer. using variant allows bar to be either an owner or a viewer, if it's a viewer then the string_view constructor should be used to set bar as a viewer and string constructor(s) as an owner.

Comment: i'd suggest against using a complex type like variant unless you can prove there will be sig benefit.  also unclear what "only changes upon being moved" means, a move doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ChrisKushnir  It's OK to not own the string, hence a solution that does not use `std::string` is acceptable. I've updated the question as using `std::string` is not part of the requirement.

Comment: @ChrisKushnir For your second comment, I think you meant `std::move` doesn't change anything, while moving does mutate things. I clarified the question. `bar` is only changed upon `Foo` being moved from.

Comment: @xuhdev shouldn't you be able to leverage `constexpr` with string literals?

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Could you be a bit more concrete? I still don't see any way to not copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can (sort of) overload on literalness using a UDL operator

```
struct literal_string {
    const char *v;
    literal_string(const char *p): v(p) {}
};
constexpr literal_string operator””_l(const char *p) {return p;}
```

Add the constructor

```
Foo(literal_string)
```

And you can now (basically) overload on literalness with `Foo(“a string”_l)`

Edit:

To solve the lifetime management problem without unnecessary cookies, I would use `std::string_view` in Foo and allocate a separate `std::string` for temporaries

```
auto f1 = Foo(“a string”_l);

std::string foo_string = tempStr();
auto f2 = Foo(foo_string);
```

Comment: While not exactly what I want, this certainly helps :)